# AEM URL Rewriting

Tags: aem, sling

I can see broadly two approaches for URL rewriting in AEM:

1. Sling mapping (sling:Mapping) under /etc/map/http(s)
2. URL rewriting using link rewriter/TransformerFactory.

I want to know which one is better among two - in sense of ease of implementation, scalability, maintenance & automation.

Regards.

Comment: anything else apart from two approaches above?

Comment: One more option at dispatcher level - [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Comparison is broad topic, probably fellow SO members can suggest.

Comment: with mod_rewrite only, we may undermine AEM/sling features - both are a combo.

Answer (score 8):

there are always multiple options to a problem in Sling. If you look at the topic "URL rewriting" it has two dimensions:

- outbound - e.g. shorten links `/content/path/en/about.html` to `/en/about/`
- inbound - e.g. map an inbound request from `/en/about/` to a resoure request `/content/path/en/about.html`

**Outbound**:
URL rewriting is usually be done outbound by a LinkRewriter/TransformerFactory. 
In theory, you could also change your component to render differently or change your content. But that's not recommended.
To apply a Transformer you can use

- /etc/map mapping (**recommended**), referred to as Mapping Map Entries [1]

  - enhanced mapping allowing for complex rules, also for regex-based rules
  - allows for different mapping per domain or protocol
  - can ensure complete externalization of links
- ResourceResolver Map Entries [1]

  - traditional mapping, very simple rules only
  - Does not take domain or protocol into account
  - requires resolver restart on change (can be expensive for large production environments)
- Custom TransformerFactory

  - full power to change all links on the way out based on Sax+custom rules

**Inbound**:
Your inbound requests can be rewritten or mapped on Sling or at infrastructure levels before (Apache HTTPD mod_rewrite or CDN s.a. Akamai)

- Apache **HTTPD mod_rewrite** (**recommended for production**) - modify the request before it gets forwarded to the Dispatcher module. Recommended as it allows for enhanced security as well as for proper and simple caching and de-caching rules
- **Sling** - usually not for production, as caching might become difficult

  - /etc/map
  - ResourceResolver
  - RequestFilter [2]
  - NonExistingResource servlet
- **CDN**: same as mod_rewrite. Inbound manipulation before the request reaches the Dispatcher

HTH

[1]
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/configuring/resource-mapping.html

[2]
https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html

[3] 
https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html

Answer (score 5):

This depends on which rewriting are you referring to. Inbound or Outbound.

When it comes to Inbound rewriting I'd advise to use mod_rewrite and just properly rewrite your content there with a single rule - this is quite efficient.

When it comes to Outbound rewriting (handling links in your html) you should definitely go with Sling Mappings - as they are more efficient and clear - and they are designed just for this purpose.

Take a look at this blog which explains the whole rewriting journey: https://www.cognifide.com/our-blogs/cq/multidomain-cq-mappings-and-apache-configuration/